# Zend Framework: This row has been marked read-only

Tags: zend-framework

This is the first time I've come across this issue. When saving one of my models I get the error message: "This row has been marked read-only". Not sure why I'm getting this error and how to solve it. The stack trace didn't help me. How can I resolve this issue so I can save the record?

Comment: Was the record retrieved as part of a query that used a join or did the select disable the setIntegrityCheck flag?

Comment: possibly...why do you ask? Am I not allowed to join other data on the model if I am going to save it later?

Comment: If either were the case, then the row object returned will be marked as read only because the integrity check is turned off and it doesn't guarantee that the object is compatible with the table object anymore so you can't directly update it, you'd have to create a new object of your row class and copy the data to it.

Comment: That makes sense. You should move this into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 9):

Having a row marked as read only can be the result from any of the following operations:

- The `Zend_Db_Select` query joined with another table
- `setIntegrityCheck(false)` was set on the select object
- One or more columns is the result of an evaluated expression

If any of the above conditions are true, then the resulting row object will be marked as read only, because Zend_Db cannot guarantee that all columns in the result reference the original parent table of the select object.  Therefore any attempt to call `update()`, `save()`, or `delete()`, on the row object will fail.

Some of this information is spread throughout the [Zend_Db_Table reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html), where if you search for `integrity` you can see a number of instances where rows will be marked read only.

Comment: possible typo - I believe `setIntegrityCheck(TRUE)` is what you meant as we normally set it to `FALSE` to allow joins. Although I could have the context backwards.

Comment: It's correct, if you disable the integrity check `setIntegrityCheck(false)` then the row is marked read only.  If the integrity check is on, and it passes, then the row is mutable.