# Zend Framework: SetIntegrityCheck(false) and then update the object

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table, zend-db-select

I am getting data from two tables using join and putting `setIntegrityCheck(false)` in my model. Now I need to call `save()` on that object. I know when you put `setIntegrityCheck(false)`, you cannot call `save()`, `delete()` or `update()` to this object. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355442/zend-framework-this-row-has-been-marked-read-only) question, but it doesn't address the answer.

So any way around?

Answer (score 0):

ZF supports only Table data gateway and row data gateway pattern. AFAIK `setIntegrityCheck()` will only allow you to join tables within Db_Table_Select which will help you to build SQL query. Anyway you can not hydrate custom SQL results to Db_Table_Row objects - which supports `save()`. You have to simply update each row separatly. For more sofisticated approach you will have to use data mapper pattern - like Doctrine.